# Enable drag and drop into Visual Studio 2008 from Windows Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

Is there some way to enable Visual Studio 2008 to accept dropped files from Windows explorer?

I can't count the number of times I've instinctively dragged a file into VS just to be reminded of this obvious feature than seems to be missing.

Surely there has to be some way to do this.

---

**EDIT**

I did find the [VS Explorer](http://www.ssware.com/vsexplorer/vsexplorer.htm) addin while searching for an answer to this. I like it, but it would still be nice to have drag and drop from explorer.

---

**EDIT II**

To clarify I would like to be able to open projects/solutions and individual files (xml,.c,.cpp,etc) by dropping them. Like right now, I have this XML file I want to take a look at in VS. I have my project open, but I can't drag the XML file into VS to open it. I have to File...Open...

Comment: I see what you mean, initially thoght you meant adding a file to a solution by dragging

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works out of the box.

However, if you are running Visual Studio as Administrator or as another user (diferent user from your currently logged in Windows user) Windows doesn't allow this kind of operation.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I was using Debugger.Break to debug into a .NET Windows service and when not running as admin I can't debug with the already open Visual Studio instance unless it is running as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on what you get, I can do this ok...Drag from windows explorer into a VS solution?

It is default functionality. dragging a file will open usually.

What happens when you try to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good discussion on this topic that covers a slightly different workflow at:

[Drag and drop doesn't work in Visual Studio 2008, but does out of it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/b56afbcf-3f3c-4ea3-b23a-274505534de1)